# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Routing for Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

How can I configure routing to enable different users to use their own distinct url when accessing the site?  I want to display their logo and other customization upon initial visit.

Something like this:

```
mysite.com\customer1
mysite.com\customer2
```

I would much prefer the following, but I believe this is not possible.

```
customer1.mysite.com
customer2.mysite.com
```

Is their a better way to achieve this intent?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a routing concern.

You can have multiple subdomains pointing to the same application, and then use [middleware](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/middleware) to resolve which domain was used and set values accordingly:

```
public class DomainResolverMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DomainResolverMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }


    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var host = context.Request.Host.ToString();
        // do whatever
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```